# Migrating network from VMware to Virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vmware-workstation

I need to get the following scheme:

my computer should be in the 2 networks: in the a `real` one network (for internet, it can be wifi or lan or something other) and the second `virtual` network (where my pc is a  member of virtual network). `Virtual machines must also have Internet access.`

[image: network]

I did it easily, using vmware workstation:

1. Creating network as NAT.
2. Specifying gateway as 10.1.1.1 in the NAT settings (Virtual Network Editor).
3. Specifying host ip 10.1.1.2 and gateway 10.1.1.1 in the virtual interface of host-machine (vmnet8).
4. Specifying NAT in the virtual machines settings.
5. Specifying the ip address like 10.1.1.x in the virtual machines.

Unfortunately my trial period has expired. So, I tried to do something similar with Virtualbox, but could not. If I specifying NAT in the virtual machine settings, I can get access to the Internet only, and did not see my real computer. It seems that the system only works with 10.0.2.x subnet and via dhcp only..

When I tried to specify virtual adapter, I was able to get a network connection between the real and the virtual machine. But the Internet did not work.

How can I get a working solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Server Fault is not personal desktop support - please see our [FAQ] for a detailed explanation of what is considered to be on-topic here. You should also consider ***reading the documentation for any tool you intend to use*** (specifically the VirtualBox documentation on their NAT networking implementation, which explains how you access the host system)

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get a working solution?

Pay for it.  Really.  Either you need to get a production-grade solution (like VMWare ESXi or Xen), or not do it on the likes of VirtualBox, because trying will only bring you pain down the road.

And, in all seriousness, if you can find supported hardware, there's nothing wrong with using the free version of ESXi for virtualizing a bunch of workstation machines on your laptop.